# What changes do i need to shift my results reflected from Cell A2 to D2

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

a = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value = "shipment oi" Then

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    b = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    End If
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

[Code manages to reflect from A2 onwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFnz5.png)

[How do I make it reflect in D2 instead?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSiyW.png)

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 4).Select`

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 4).Select`. The 2nd argument of `Cells` indicates the column number of the cell so 4 is column D. Also you will benefit from reading on [how to avoid using select/activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1)

Comment: @braX Thank you for your input! but im now facing an error that reflects Run time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error. any idea on this? much appreciated for your help. I'm a complete novice in VBA.

Comment: @RaymondWu Thank you for your input! but im now facing an error that reflects Run time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error. any idea on this? much appreciated for your help. I'm a complete novice in VBA.

Comment: Which line did the error occur? @Rahman

Comment: Since you are now pasting to column D, you might want to get the last row of column D instead so `b = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("sheet2").Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row`